# Create a Question and answer form in javascript with comparison?

Tags: javascript, forms

I was wondering if you knew of a script where I have a form including a question and right below I ask the user to type in the box an answer and when pressing submit, an answer appears along with highlighting or something that'll tell where the user is right or wrong.

It's kind of like those flashcard games where you type something in and get an answer back.

If not, is there a more specific forum for this kind of thing?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any particular script to do this, but it wouldn't be difficult to construct a custom one.  I did this using jQuery: http://jsfiddle.net/brianflanagan/3KyRm/

I kept this fairly simple to demonstrate as a proof-of-concept.  I wouldn't recommend building a quiz that includes the answers in the source code as it would be far too easy to cheat.  :)  A better solution would incorporate a form submission or AJAX handler.